# Upgraded to1.9.2.2 and now user registration not working

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

update to 1.9.2.2 users are unable to register on the site.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you upgraded magento if you have the following files that your have overridden in your theme you will need to add the following for customer registration to work: 
`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Files:

[`app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/{your_package}/template/customer/form/register.phtml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml#L46)

[`app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/{your_package}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml#L45)

Comment: Hi Rob, in my theme haven't the file in first row that you write but I have only the second file in persistent folder.

Comment: Have you other Suggest?

Comment: so you have the `app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/{your_package}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` file in your theme? Have you added the line here https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml#L45

Comment: I browse and in my theme there is only register.phtml under persistent/customer/form. I followed the instruction how shows the link to github, but not work. Every time I check and register on site, after filled all date and submit the form, the page reload with empty form.

Comment: On the live site can you inspect the page and see if the following key exists on the page <input type="hidden" name="form_key">

Comment: It not exist.  But I have inserted the script on file...

Comment: have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, more time.. I use on site IWD onepage checkout, it can create a conflict?

Comment: Possibly maybe check with the IWD guys to see if they have released an upgrade for their module

Comment: Yes, the problem is OPC by IWD. I added the script in file register.html under: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/opc/customer/form ... now it work well. Thans very much.

Comment: you're welcome glad it worked

Comment: Well thanks, I add another fix, all the extension that use registration form must update with this script. In another site have this issue: In italian configuration I use Magenio Tax code and VAT, this module must update with this code to use registration form on site.

Comment: Correct any modules that override the customer registration form must have this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, there may be more extensions overriding your register.phtml file other than your custom themes. Turn on your path hints (system>config>advanced>developer) and check to see if any extensions are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is using OPC, add form_key in register.phtml on opc files. 
Works fine.