# Supee 6788 isn't installed after upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: upgrade, patches, supee-6788, ce-1.9.2.2

I did the upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.2 with Magento Connect but after doing that still appear the message "October 27, 2015: New Magento Security Patch (SUPEE-6788) – Install Immediately".

It's possible?

Comment: Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74608/security-patch-supee-6285-install-immediately-in-magento-1-9-0-1/74618#74618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento CE 1.9.2.2 includes the fix of all security issues that are addressed by Patch SUPEE-6788. So there is no need to apply the patch once you have done a proper upgrade.

To take full advantage of all new security features go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security` and set `Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions` to "Disable". [More details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88435/admin-routing-compatibility-mode-for-extensions-enable-or-disable)

Don't forget to check the customer registration forms for your store. If you use customer registration template files in your custom theme then make sure the `form_key` is added to those files. [More details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88431/upgraded-to1-9-2-2-and-now-user-registration-not-working/)

Also check whether all variables and blocks that your store is using are added to the white list in `System > Permissions > Variables` and `System > Permissions > Blocks` [More details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87974)

And now the answer to your question...

The message you see comes from the notifications inbox. This message will **not** disappear when upgrading to Magento CE 1.9.2.2 (and also not when applying Patch SUPEE-6788).

You will have to do this manually (in both cases). Go to `System > Notifications` and mark this message as read or remove it from your Messages Inbox.